# Defined Value resets back to 0 once passed through if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

Right now I am trying to build a basic blackjack game using python. The problem that is occurring regards calculating the total of the users cards. Every time the user decides to draw a new card instead of adding it to the card total they have, my program instead adds it into 0 and not the total that the user actually has. Any explanation would be appreciated

```
import random
cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
users_cards = []
card_count = len(users_cards)
user_total = 0
computer_cards = []
computer_total = 0

def get_hand(user_total):
    x = random.randint(0, 12)
    y = int(cards[x])
    users_cards.append(y)
    user_total += y
    x = random.randint(0, 12)
    y = int(cards[x])
    user_total += y
    users_cards.append(y)
    print(f'{users_cards[0]} {users_cards[1]}')
    print(f'Your total is {user_total}')

def get_card(user_total):
    x = random.randint(0, 12)
    y = int(cards[x])
    users_cards.append(y)
    card_count = len(users_cards)
    print(f'Your new card is {users_cards[card_count - 1]}')
    user_total += y
    print(f'Your total is {user_total}')


def computer_hand(computer_cards,computer_total):
    x = random.randint(0, 12)
    y = int(cards[x])
    computer_cards.append(y)
    computer_total += y
    x = random.randint(0, 12)
    y = int(cards[x])
    computer_total += y
    computer_cards.append(y)
    print(f'One of your opponents cards is {computer_cards[0]}')
    #print(computer_cards)

computer_hand(computer_cards,computer_total)
get_hand(user_total)
get_another_card = input('Do you want to draw another card? Yes or No ').lower()

if get_another_card == 'yes':
    get_card(user_total)
else:
    for every_card in users_cards:
        user_total += every_card
    print(user_total)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in the `user_total` variable as a parameter into the function `get_card()` and then changing that parameter which doesn't change the `user_total` variable you defined earlier because you aren't returning anything. The same is true with your other functions.

You could return `user_total` and then reassign it

```py
def get_card(user_total):
    x = random.randint(0, 12)
    y = int(cards[x])
    users_cards.append(y)
    card_count = len(users_cards)
    print(f'Your new card is {users_cards[card_count - 1]}')
    user_total += y
    print(f'Your total is {user_total}')
    
    return user_total
```

```py
user_total = get_hand(user_total)
```